# Comparison of normality + similarity distribution of time series datas

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, normal-distribution, validation, similarities

I have a training time series data , whose last 20% is kept as validation data. I want to check whether the distribution of training and validation features are similiar and normal, so that we can say that model can be fitted on validation data and is representative of training data.
How can I do this...also the size of training and validation data differ widely since validation data is only 20% of training data.
Any suggestion would be helpful !

Comment: Why do you care if the features are similar between train and validation? What is your research question, what are you trying to actually achieve? Is it prediction and selecting the best model?

Comment: We are fitting our model on validation data , after training it on training data. We are trying to analyse if the features in training data when compared with features in validation data varies extensively. Since it is a industry data , there are a lot of downtimes in validation data. We just want to see if validation data is similiar in distribution and normally distributed as training data.

Comment: @Swara I am not sure about your usage of the terms. You should try to make sure that training, validation, and test data come independently from the same population as the data that you will later apply your model to. With time-series data, the independence part might be tricky.

Comment: Yeah , i want to make sure validation data has the similiar distribution as the validation data... that's what I'm wondering how to do. I tried welch t test , 2 sided kolmogrov smirnov test, mean comparison. Is there something I am missing or which i could try..

Comment: This won't be easy, because you would probably have to check whether the multivariate distribution is similar between train and validation, and not using univariate tests/plots, as you suggest. For ex. in your training data you may find that two variables are distributed normally around 0, but in your training data they would have a positive correlation, while in your validation set they might have a negative correlation. You would not identify this using univariate approaches.

Comment: Will 2 sample KS test help in finding the similiarity in these 2 distributions ? I tried it but i am getting p value of 0.0 for most of the features and hardly any above 0.05